# How to Install VSCode on Windows as Administrator for data science projects without painful debugging and re-installations later?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I see a lot of misleading advice from newbie and non-system programmers that cause developers painful debugging and many lost hours that usually require reinstalling VSCode and Anaconda on Windows.

I have lost days of time fixing my own VSCode installations and other people's setups by letting Microsoft IT-targeted default installers choose installation locations in under-privileged user account folders, specifically the "AppData" directory.

Microsoft recently came out with VSCode "universal installer" that favors big corporate IT shops, at the expense of fast agile developers of system administration tools, data analytics tools and data science applications.  This puts developers at a disadvantage at the mercy of IT support.  Over the past two years, I had big delay times (many days to weeks) waiting for IT shops to finally reinstall VSCode with system administrator privileges.  This was in both small IT shops (small biotechs), large (Fortune 100) IT shops, and small training institutes.  This posed horrible hits for productivity across the board if the organization doesn't have a big DevOps budget.

What I need: to provide a single link that ALWAYS provides the latest version of the VSCode System Installer (to install with full LOCAL administrator privileges.)

What I tried:

1. To modify the installer (failed after Microsoft updated it).
2. To provide my users with a single link to ALWAYS install the latest version of the System Installer. (This failed because eventually Microsoft took away the master link to the system installer.)

I need to avoid painful debugging and losing days of time.

Some of the naysayers below appear to work for Microsoft or big IT shops and they think this is not a real problem.

Comment: I'm curious what these purported privilege issues are. Microsoft actually recommends most people to install the user setup because it doesn't require admin privileges to perform updates on. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_user-setup-versus-system-setup. And why does this question need to have anything to do with GH Copilot? What about the installation privilege issues has specifically to do with GH Copilot? And what exactly do you mean by "systems work"? It's hard for me to mentally combine anaconda with systems programming, and unclear what you're actually referring to...

Comment: My experience is mainly for data scientists and AI team leaders.  To have VSCode play nicely with conda environments, miniconda, and data science environments and distributions like Anaconda, I prefer to install all tools as administrator.  

Then I don't have to hunt in folders "c:\users\<user_account>\AppDir" in user accounts to find conda virtual environments which VSCode puts there.  If you install VSCode as Admin then you are assured that all conda virtual environments will be in one place, i.e., "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\<your conda environment>".   Debugging is much easier.

Comment: @starball This has more to do with centralizing virtual environments and increasing developer productivity by getting and keeping corporate IT out of the way.  Microsoft wants to make it easy for corporate IT shops to centralize systems management, i.e., create, delete, hire/fire any users. 

If user installation WITH system administrator privileges when installing VSCode, then they will always INTENTIONALLY have these privileges.  They have what they need by default, without exception.  Give developers the direct control they need to unify and streamline their own work.

Comment: @topsail I fail to see how it is "a huge security plus not to have to run your IDE with admin privileges."  This is EXACTLY what I need to do.  I don't have the time to raise IT tickets and wait for Corporate IT to do anything for me at all.  The Microsoft installer defaults to regular end user-only privileges, which are insufficient to get my developer work done.

Answer (score -1):

I created this set of instructions for people to follow.

#1) First make sure you are using an account with full System Administrator privileges to install (all) your tools.

**Download and Install VSCode**

- Go to the Visual Studio Code download page:     https://code.visualstudio.com/download
- Choose and download the **SYSTEM INSTALLER** version that matches your OS (Windows, Linux, or macOS).
- WARNING: `*(DO NOT USE the "User Installer", because it will bury packages into an under-privileged "regular user" directory: "%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\", which will cause problems and make debugging work much harder later.)*` ***MAKE SURE TO CHOOSE THE "SYSTEM INSTALLER"***
- Run installer and pay close attention to the prompts in the setup wizard.
- Verify System Installer uses location "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code".
- As a system administrator, you can check the boxes that add VSCode to your system PATH and that create a desktop icon.
- Once the installation is complete, you can launch VSCode.

**Configure VSCode**

- After launching VSCode, you can customize it to your liking. You can install and change themes, keybindings, settings, and more by going to `File > Preferences` and editing the ominous settings.json file. (do this later because Copilot can help you tweak 100s of settings in VSCode.
- You can also install extensions to add more functionality to VSCode. Extensions can be installed from the Extensions view, which can be opened by clicking on the Extensions icon in the Activity Bar on the side of the window.

**Installing GitHub Copilot**

- Open the Extensions view in VSCode.
- Search for "GitHub Copilot".
- Click on the Install button.

**Create a GitHub Account** (if you don't already have one.)

- Go to the GitHub signup page: https://github.com/join
- Fill out the form with your desired username, email address, and password.
- Click on the "Create account" button.
- Follow the prompts to complete the account creation process.

**Enable GitHub Copilot**

- After installing the GitHub Copilot extension in VSCode, it should be enabled by default. You can check if it's enabled by going to `File > Preferences > Extensions`, find GitHub Copilot, and make sure the checkbox next to it is checked.
- You MUST sign in to your GitHub account for GitHub Copilot to work. To do this click on the GitHub icon in the Activity Bar, then click on "Sign in to GitHub.com" button.

**How to Use GitHub Copilot**

- To start using GitHub Copilot, simply add a comment in a file in VSCode editor window or Jupyter Notebook that describes the functionality you want it to generate, hit Enter, wait a few seconds, and GitHub Copilot will automatically generate code and suggest completions as you type.
- Accept a suggestion by pressing `Tab` or `Enter`, or ignore it and continue typing.
- Manually trigger suggestions by pressing `Ctrl+Enter`.
- Watch some of the MANY YouTube videos to learn dozens of tips and tricks on how to be super-productive with Copilot.

Remember, as a system administrator, you might need to provide administrator permissions at various steps in this process.

Comment: It is not necessary to install VSCode with admin privileges, nor is it necessarily bad for it to be installed in a user's local directories. It could be argued this is bad advice. I certainly would not follow these instructions.

Comment: This recommendation is mainly for data science and AI developers.  To have VSCode play nicely with conda environments, miniconda, and data science environments and distributions like Anaconda, I prefer to install all tools as administrator.  

Then I don't have to hunt around for "c:\users\<user_account>\AppDir" in user accounts to find conda virtual environments which VSCode puts there.  If you install VSCode as Admin then you are assured that all conda virtual environments will be in one place, i.e., "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\<your conda environment>".   Debugging is much easier.

Comment: It could be argued this is EXCELLENT advice, especially for developers who have time to waste and don't favor big corporate IT Shops or Microsoft's heavy-handed installation policies baked into their tools.